# one-to-many relation in Kohana

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I have 3 tables `users` , `roles` and `roles_users`. The `roles_users` table have `user_id` and `role_id`

Now my models are `Model_User`, `Model_Role`, `Model_User_Role`.

How can i link the three models so that every user is associated to one role and one role has many users.

I am using ORM and i want to display the list of users with the name of there role.

Note: The table i have taken from `Auth` Module of Kohana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_belongs_to`, `$_has_one` and `$_has_many` arrays to set relationship between the models.
[Kohana 3 :: ORM Relationships](http://kohanaframework.blogspot.com/2010/12/kohana-3-orm-relationships.html)

Comment: If you want to make such relationship as you discribe why you don't exclude Model_User_Role table?
You can add field "role_id" in users db table and set
`protected $_belongs_to = arry(
 'role' => array('model' => 'role', 'foreign_key' => 'role_id'),
);`
in Model_Users and
`protected $_has_many = arry(
 'user' => array('model' => 'user', 'foreign_key' => 'role_id'),
);`
in Model_Role

Comment: but i am following the auth module of Kohana and it has that table

Comment: You can make your own auth models, based on /modules/auth/classes/model/auth/user.php and /modules/auth/classes/model/auth/role.php, and set required relations

Answer (score 1):

I did a many to many relation with roles and users. And will write business logic that a users will not have more than one roles.